# Google Kubernetes Engine: Not seeing mount persistent volume in the instance

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I created a 200G disk with the command `gcloud compute disks create --size 200GB my-disk`

then created a PersistentVolume

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolume
    metadata:
      name: my-volume
    spec:
      capacity:
        storage: 200Gi
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      gcePersistentDisk:
        pdName: my-disk
        fsType: ext4
```

then created a PersistentVolumeClaim

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      name: my-claim
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 200Gi
```

then created a StatefulSet and mount the volume to /mnt/disks, which is an existing directory. statefulset.yaml:

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
    kind: StatefulSet
    metadata:
      name: ...
    spec:
        ...
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: ...
            ...
            volumeMounts:
            - name: my-volume
              mountPath: /mnt/disks
          volumes:
          - name: my-volume
            emptyDir: {}
      volumeClaimTemplates:
      - metadata:
          name: my-claim
        spec:
          accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 200Gi
```

I ran command `kubectl get pv` and saw that disk was successfully mounted to each instance

```
    NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM                                    STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
    my-volume                                  200Gi      RWO            Retain           Available                                                                     19m
    pvc-17c60f45-2e4f-11e8-9b77-42010af0000e   200Gi      RWO            Delete           Bound       default/my-claim-xxx_1   standard                 13m
    pvc-5972c804-2e4e-11e8-9b77-42010af0000e   200Gi      RWO            Delete           Bound       default/my-claim                         standard                 18m
    pvc-61b9daf9-2e4e-11e8-9b77-42010af0000e   200Gi      RWO            Delete           Bound       default/my-claimxxx_0   standard                 18m
```

but when I ssh into an instance and run `df -hT`, I do not see the mounted volume. below is the output:

```
    Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/root      ext2      1.2G  447M  774M  37% /
    devtmpfs       devtmpfs  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
    tmpfs          tmpfs     1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
    tmpfs          tmpfs     1.9G  744K  1.9G   1% /run
    tmpfs          tmpfs     1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    tmpfs          tmpfs     1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /tmp
    tmpfs          tmpfs     256K     0  256K   0% /mnt/disks
    /dev/sda8      ext4       12M   28K   12M   1% /usr/share/oem
    /dev/sda1      ext4       95G  3.5G   91G   4% /mnt/stateful_partition
    tmpfs          tmpfs     1.0M  128K  896K  13% /var/lib/cloud
    overlayfs      overlay   1.0M  148K  876K  15% /etc
```

anyone has any idea?

Also worth mentioning that I'm trying to mount the disk to a docker image which is running in kubernete engine. The pod was created with below commands:

```
    docker build -t gcr.io/xxx .
    gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/xxx
    kubectl create -f statefulset.yaml
```

The instance I sshed into is the one that runs the docker image. I do not see the volume in both instance and the docker container

**UPDATE**
I found the volume, I ran `df -ahT` in the instance, and saw the relevant entries

```
    /dev/sdb       -               -     -     -    - /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/gke-xxx-cluster-c-pvc-61b9daf9-2e4e-11e8-9b77-42010af0000e
    /dev/sdb       -               -     -     -    - /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/gke-xxx-cluster-c-pvc-61b9daf9-2e4e-11e8-9b77-42010af0000e
    /dev/sdb       -               -     -     -    - /home/kubernetes/containerized_mounter/rootfs/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/gke-xxx-cluster-c-pvc-61b9daf9-2e4e-11e8-9b77-42010af0000e
    /dev/sdb       -               -     -     -    - /home/kubernetes/containerized_mounter/rootfs/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/gke-xxx-cluster-c-pvc-61b9daf9-2e4e-11e8-9b77-42010af0000e
    /dev/sdb       -               -     -     -    - /var/lib/kubelet/pods/61bb679b-2e4e-11e8-9b77-42010af0000e/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pvc-61b9daf9-2e4e-11e8-9b77-42010af0000e
    /dev/sdb       -               -     -     -    - /var/lib/kubelet/pods/61bb679b-2e4e-11e8-9b77-42010af0000e/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pvc-61b9daf9-2e4e-11e8-9b77-42010af0000e
    /dev/sdb       -               -     -     -    - /home/kubernetes/containerized_mounter/rootfs/var/lib/kubelet/pods/61bb679b-2e4e-11e8-9b77-42010af0000e/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pvc-61b9daf9-2e4e-11e8-9b77-42010af0000e
    /dev/sdb       -               -     -     -    - /home/kubernetes/containerized_mounter/rootfs/var/lib/kubelet/pods/61bb679b-2e4e-11e8-9b77-42010af0000e/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/pvc-61b9daf9-2e4e-11e8-9b77-42010af0000e
```

then I went into the docker container and ran `df -ahT`, I got

```
    Filesystem     Type     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/sda1      ext4      95G  3.5G   91G   4% /mnt/disks
```

Why I'm seeing 95G total size instead of 200G, which is the size of my volume?

More info:
`kubectl describe pod`

```
    Name:           xxx-replicaset-0
    Namespace:      default
    Node:           gke-xxx-cluster-default-pool-5e49501c-nrzt/10.128.0.17
    Start Time:     Fri, 23 Mar 2018 11:40:57 -0400
    Labels:         app=xxx-replicaset
                    controller-revision-hash=xxx-replicaset-755c4f7cff
    Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"StatefulSet","namespace":"default","name":"xxx-replicaset","uid":"d6c3511f-2eaf-11e8-b14e-42010af0000...
                    kubernetes.io/limit-ranger=LimitRanger plugin set: cpu request for container xxx-deployment
    Status:         Running
    IP:             10.52.4.5
    Created By:     StatefulSet/xxx-replicaset
    Controlled By:  StatefulSet/xxx-replicaset
    Containers:
      xxx-deployment:
        Container ID:   docker://137b3966a14538233ed394a3d0d1501027966b972d8ad821951f53d9eb908615
        Image:          gcr.io/sampeproject/xxxstaging:v1
        Image ID:       docker-pullable://gcr.io/sampeproject/xxxstaging@sha256:a96835c2597cfae3670a609a69196c6cd3d9cc9f2f0edf5b67d0a4afdd772e0b
        Port:           8080/TCP
        State:          Running
          Started:      Fri, 23 Mar 2018 11:42:17 -0400
        Ready:          True
        Restart Count:  0
        Requests:
          cpu:        100m
        Environment:  
        Mounts:
          /mnt/disks from my-volume (rw)
          /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-hj65g (ro)
    Conditions:
      Type           Status
      Initialized    True
      Ready          True
      PodScheduled   True
    Volumes:
      my-claim:
        Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
        ClaimName:  my-claim-xxx-replicaset-0
        ReadOnly:   false
      my-volume:
        Type:    EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
        Medium:
      default-token-hj65g:
        Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
        SecretName:  default-token-hj65g
        Optional:    false
    QoS Class:       Burstable
    Node-Selectors:  
    Tolerations:     node.alpha.kubernetes.io/notReady:NoExecute for 300s
                     node.alpha.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
    Events:
      Type     Reason                 Age                From                                                      Message
      ----     ------                 ----               ----                                                      -------
      Warning  FailedScheduling       10m (x4 over 10m)  default-scheduler                                         PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "my-claim-xxx-replicaset-0" (repeated 5 times)
      Normal   Scheduled              9m                 default-scheduler                                         Successfully assigned xxx-replicaset-0 to gke-xxx-cluster-default-pool-5e49501c-nrzt
      Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  9m                 kubelet, gke-xxx-cluster-default-pool-5e49501c-nrzt  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "my-volume"
      Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  9m                 kubelet, gke-xxx-cluster-default-pool-5e49501c-nrzt  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-hj65g"
      Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  9m                 kubelet, gke-xxx-cluster-default-pool-5e49501c-nrzt  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "pvc-902c57c5-2eb0-11e8-b14e-42010af0000e"
      Normal   Pulling                9m                 kubelet, gke-xxx-cluster-default-pool-5e49501c-nrzt  pulling image "gcr.io/sampeproject/xxxstaging:v1"
      Normal   Pulled                 8m                 kubelet, gke-xxx-cluster-default-pool-5e49501c-nrzt  Successfully pulled image "gcr.io/sampeproject/xxxstaging:v1"
      Normal   Created                8m                 kubelet, gke-xxx-cluster-default-pool-5e49501c-nrzt  Created container
      Normal   Started                8m                 kubelet, gke-xxx-cluster-default-pool-5e49501c-nrzt  Started container
```

Seems like it did not mount the correct volume. I ran `lsblk` in docker container

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

    sda       8:0    0  100G  0 disk 
    ├─sda1    8:1    0 95.9G  0 part /mnt/disks
    ├─sda2    8:2    0   16M  0 part 
    ├─sda3    8:3    0    2G  0 part 
    ├─sda4    8:4    0   16M  0 part 
    ├─sda5    8:5    0    2G  0 part 
    ├─sda6    8:6    0  512B  0 part 
    ├─sda7    8:7    0  512B  0 part 
    ├─sda8    8:8    0   16M  0 part 
    ├─sda9    8:9    0  512B  0 part 
    ├─sda10   8:10   0  512B  0 part 
    ├─sda11   8:11   0    8M  0 part 
    └─sda12   8:12   0   32M  0 part 
    sdb       8:16   0  200G  0 disk
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: Try looking at volumes or claims with `kubectl describe`. Also look at `kubectl get events` when you create these objects. There might be some silent failures. Also please consider properly using the code block syntax. I didn't read your question because it was too hard to read.

Comment: Thanks, I reformatted the code, and also added the output of `kubectl describe pv`, `kubectl describe pvc` and `kubectl get events`. I don't see any issue.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Looks like it actually not mounted on the node and docker showing you the size of your root disk. Can you share somehow a result of kubectl describe $pod command? If it is possible - remove a pod (RC will create a new one), wait 1 minute and call that command.

Comment: Sure, I added the output of `kubectl describe pod` after the pod was recreated

Comment: I found the reason, the yaml config is wrong

Answer (score 1):

When you use PVCs, K8s manages persistent disks for you.

The exact way how PVs can by defined by provisioner in storage classes. Since you use GKE your default SC uses kubernetes.io/gce-pd provisioner (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#gce).

In other words for each pod new PV is created.

If you would like to use existing disk you can use Volumes instead of PVCs (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#gcepersistentdisk)

Answer (score 0):

The PVC is not mounted into your container because you did not actually specify the PVC in your container's volumeMounts.  Only the emptyDir volume was specified.

I actually recently modified the GKE StatefulSet [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/stateful-apps).  Before, some of the steps were incorrect and saying to manually create the PD and PV objects.  Instead, it's been corrected to use dynamic provisioning.

Please try that out and see if the updated steps work for you.