# GKE available disc size for pod and volume different

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, monitoring, metrics, mounted-volumes

I have a mysql deployment with one single pod that requires storage. That is why it is bound on /var/lib/mysql to a volume of 250G capacity via a pvc. Executing into the container and checking out available disc size the values do NOT add up: On /var/lib/mysql it shows me only 9.5G available instead of the 250G.

Executing df inside the linux container shows only 9.5G total disc size and 4% used:

```
nim@DESKTOP-FOASM6G:/home$ kubectl exec mysql-7947979f68-74plp -- df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          95G  2.5G   92G   3% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        95G  2.5G   92G   3% /etc/hosts
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb        9.9G  307M  9.5G   4% /var/lib/mysql
tmpfs           2.4G   12K  2.4G   1% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/firmware
```

Executing lsblk inside the linux container shows the correct 233Gi disc size but lacks usage information:

```
nim@DESKTOP-FOASM6G:/home$ kubectl exec -it mysqltest-5566cb6985-4rzcw -- lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0  100G  0 disk
|-sda1    8:1      95.9G  0 part /etc/resolv.conf
|-sda2    8:2    0   16M  0 part
|-sda3    8:3    0    2G  0 part
|-sda4    8:4    0   16M  0 part
|-sda5    8:5    0    2G  0 part
|-sda6    8:6       512B  0 part
|-sda7    8:7    0  512B  0 part
|-sda8    8:8        16M  0 part
|-sda9    8:9    0  512B  0 part
|-sda10   8:10   0  512B  0 part
|-sda11   8:11        8M  0 part
`-sda12   8:12   0   32M  0 part
sdb       8:16   0  233G  0 disk /var/lib/mysql
```

Mysql pod description:

```
nim@DESKTOP-FOASM6G:~$ kubectl describe pod mysql-7947979f68-74plp
Name:         mysql-7947979f68-74plp
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         gke-sblice-clust-pool-1-c1994f74-ueyy/10.156.15.207
Start Time:   Wed, 19 Jul 2023 13:18:04 +0200
Labels:       app=sql
              pod-template-hash=7947979f68
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.16.1.11
IPs:
  IP:           10.16.1.11
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mysql-7947979f68
Containers:
  mysql:
    Container ID:   containerd://c1cd6e60c0f20956ca4146c315dd0665f2d1bb2eee0351e719a813a2ca62d87c
    Image:          mysql:5.6
    Image ID:       docker.io/library/mysql@sha256:20575ecebe6216036d25dab5903808211f1e9ba63dc7825ac20cb975e34cfcae
    Port:           3306/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 19 Jul 2023 13:18:06 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     1
      memory:  2500M
    Requests:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  512Mi
    Liveness:  exec [bash -c mysqladmin -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD ping
] delay=30s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  exec [bash -c mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e'SELECT 1'
] delay=5s timeout=1s period=2s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD' in secret 'mysql-secrets'>  Optional: false
      MYSQL_DATABASE:       wordpress
      MYSQL_USER:           <set to the key 'MYSQL_USER' of config map 'mysql-config'>   Optional: false
      MYSQL_PASSWORD:       <set to the key 'MYSQL_PASSWORD' in secret 'mysql-secrets'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/mysql from regional-storage-180723 (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-4qncz (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  regional-storage-180723:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  regional-storage-pvc-180723
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-4qncz:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>
```

This container is bound to a pvc with description:

```
nim@DESKTOP-FOASM6G:/home$ kubectl describe pvc regional-storage-pvc-180723
Name:          regional-storage-pvc-180723
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  normal-storageclass
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-e5baeec9-435d-46b8-a442-179d54c023e6
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
               volume.kubernetes.io/selected-node: gke-sblice-clust-pool-1-c1994f74-ueyy
               volume.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      233Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
DataSource:
  APIGroup:  snapshot.storage.k8s.io
  Kind:      VolumeSnapshot
  Name:      snapshot14072023
Used By:     mysql-7947979f68-74plp
Events:      <none>
```

And the PV itself is described as:

```
nim@DESKTOP-FOASM6G:/home$ kubectl describe pv pvc-e5baeec9-435d-46b8-a442-179d54c023e6
Name:              pvc-e5baeec9-435d-46b8-a442-179d54c023e6
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
                   volume.kubernetes.io/provisioner-deletion-secret-name:
                   volume.kubernetes.io/provisioner-deletion-secret-namespace:
Finalizers:        [kubernetes.io/pv-protection external-attacher/pd-csi-storage-gke-io]
StorageClass:      normal-storageclass
Status:            Bound
Claim:             default/regional-storage-pvc-180723
Reclaim Policy:    Retain
Access Modes:      RWO
VolumeMode:        Filesystem
Capacity:          233Gi
Node Affinity:
  Required Terms:
    Term 0:        topology.gke.io/zone in [europe-west3-b]
    Term 1:        topology.gke.io/zone in [europe-west3-c]
Message:
Source:
    Type:              CSI (a Container Storage Interface (CSI) volume source)
    Driver:            pd.csi.storage.gke.io
    FSType:            ext4
    VolumeHandle:      projects/sblice/regions/europe-west3/disks/pvc-e5baeec9-435d-46b8-a442-179d54c023e6
    ReadOnly:          false
    VolumeAttributes:      storage.kubernetes.io/csiProvisionerIdentity=1689594187853-2313-pd.csi.storage.gke.io
Events:                <none>
```

Logs from the container:

```
nim@DESKTOP-FOASM6G:/home$ kubectl logs mysql-66fc8c8d48-v7fzd
2023-08-01 15:42:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.6.51-1debian9 started.
2023-08-01 15:42:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2023-08-01 15:42:15+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.6.51-1debian9 started.
2023-08-01 15:42:16 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2023-08-01 15:42:16 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.6.51) starting as process 1 ...
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.51 started; log sequence number 11955998372
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] RSA private key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] RSA public key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@mysql-5c96657748-fv26w' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2023-08-01 15:42:16 1 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.51'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Info regarding storage class:

```
nim@DESKTOP-FOASM6G:/home$ kubectl describe storageclass normal-storageclass
Name:            normal-storageclass
IsDefaultClass:  No
Annotations:     kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"allowVolumeExpansion":true,"allowedTopologies":[{"matchLabelExpressions":[{"key":"topology.gke.io/zone","values":["europe-west3-b","europe-west3-c"]}]}],"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"normal-storageclass"},"parameters":{"replication-type":"regional-pd","type":"pd-standard"},"provisioner":"pd.csi.storage.gke.io","reclaimPolicy":"Retain","volumeBindingMode":"WaitForFirstConsumer"}

Provisioner:           pd.csi.storage.gke.io
Parameters:            replication-type=regional-pd,type=pd-standard
AllowVolumeExpansion:  True
MountOptions:          <none>
ReclaimPolicy:         Retain
VolumeBindingMode:     WaitForFirstConsumer
AllowedTopologies:
  Term 0:              topology.gke.io/zone in [europe-west3-b, europe-west3-c]
Events:                <none>
```

My yaml configuration for the deployment and the pvc:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sql
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: topology.gke.io/zone
                operator: NotIn
                values:
                - europe-west3-a
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql
        env:
          # Use secret in real usage
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-secrets
              key: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: wordpress
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mysql-config
              key: MYSQL_USER
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-secrets
              key: MYSQL_PASSWORD
        resources:
          limits:
            #cpu: "1000m"
            #memory: "2.5G"
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: "1000M"
          requests:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: "500M"
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - bash
            - "-c"
            - |
              mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e'SELECT 1'
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 2
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - bash
            - "-c"
            - |
              mysqladmin -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD ping
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: regional-storage-180723
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
        #nodeSelector:
        #  location: pv
      volumes:
      - name: regional-storage-180723
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          #change claimName to bigger disc created by snapshot in case of need
          claimName: regional-storage-pvc-180723

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: regional-storage-pvc-180723
spec:
  dataSource:
    name: snapshot14072023
    kind: VolumeSnapshot
    apiGroup: snapshot.storage.k8s.io
  storageClassName: normal-storageclass
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 250G
```

Here is how I created the snapshot

```
apiVersion: snapshot.storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: VolumeSnapshotClass
metadata:
  name: regional-snapshotclass
driver: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
deletionPolicy: Delete
----
apiVersion: snapshot.storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: VolumeSnapshot
metadata:
  name: snapshot14072023
spec:
  volumeSnapshotClassName: regional-snapshotclass
  source:
    #here enter the name of the current pvc, which is becoming too small
    persistentVolumeClaimName: regional-storage-pvc
```

Kubectl tells me that I have 250G storage mounted and within the pod (using df -h service) it is telling me that I have 9.5G. lsblk service is telling me 250G. What disc space do I have available now? What do I need to do to actually get the 250G disc space mounted correctly? And if I have 250G which way do I use to check disc space usage and how can I set my limits? Because GKE console monitoring tells me also that I have much less disc space as a metric.

I tried adding a 50G dummy file inside the directory and no problem. Available space seems to go up to 11G from 9.5G, but should be much more.

[image: test]

Comment: Two things:

1/ Logs from your mysql pod ? these could help identify the issue
2/ Can you check the StorageClass and see if allowVolumeExpansion is set to true ?

Comment: I added both bits of information. AllowVolumeExpansion is true. As an addon I might add that the df function works fine, if I use a normal pvc. 

However as soon as I use a pvc prefilled using snapshots or manual create a volume using snapshots it shows me this different number. This is true for normal volumes and regional volumes as specified by my storage class.

Comment: To answer @Dion V: When I use describe pod it tells me that it is connected to that volume. On gke console the deployment is also referencing this volume. Executing lsblk inside the container even shows me the volume with correct size. It is just that df and google metrics are showing it differently. I posted the configuration yaml from the pod as well now.

Comment: I replicated your setup and it works for me. df -h tells me /dev/sdb is mounted to /var/lib/mysql and it has 245Gi of capacity
overlay          95G  4.9G   90G   6% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
/dev/sda1        95G  4.9G   90G   6% /etc/hosts
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb        246G  116M  245G   1% /var/lib/mysql
tmpfs           954M   12K  954M   1% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/firmware

Comment: Can you tell me what you exactly replicated? Did you also use a pvc based on a snapshot and a regional disk? Because like I said, a normal pvc worked for me as well. The thing is that I want it to work with snapshots and regional disks.

Comment: I used a Regional disk! No snapshots!

Comment: can you try regional disk based on snapshot?

Comment: Ok i did not read correctly. df in a regular PVC works fine but disks created from snapshots is when you have issues right ?

How did you created the snapshot ? Is it a full or a partial snapshot ?

Comment: I added the config yaml at the end. I believe it is a full snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Michelle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49442497/google-kubernetes-engine-not-seeing-mount-persistent-volume-in-the-instance) from a previous post. You may want to check if the PVC is not mounted into your container. Because you may not actually specify the PVC in your container's volumeMounts.

Here is the reference [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/stateful-apps) that you can check as well.