# How to add more storage to my job using GKE Autopilot

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, circleci, persistent-volumes

I'm trying to setup a cluster to run CircleCI jobs on GKE. I have no experience with kubernetes.

I managed to setup the cluster on GKE and to use the CircleCI-provide helm chart.

Now my jobs launch correctly but I'm running out of disk space:

```
    Warning  Evicted    0s    kubelet                                Container primary exceeded its local ephemeral storage limit "1Gi".
    Normal   Killing    0s    kubelet                                Stopping container primary
    Normal   Killing    0s    kubelet                                Stopping container logging
    Normal   Killing    0s    kubelet                                Stopping container secondary-1
    Normal   Killing    0s    kubelet                                Stopping container secondary-2
```

How can I increase storage on an Autopilot cluster?

The docs seem to indicate that ephemeral storage is limited to 1Gi.

I'm trying to attach persistent storage but I'm not sure 1. how to use it in the pod and 2. to which folder I should mount it on the pod.

I've created a disk and a PersistentVolume

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: circleci-job-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: standard
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: circleci-disk-1
    fsType: ext4
```

But I don't know how to modify my pods to use this persistent volume.

Comment: Note that I don't need persistent storage, I mainly want to have more disk space for the duration of the job, the data can be discarded when the job has run

Comment: This answer seems to say I don't actually need to create a PV and a disk and I can use a PVC directly? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49525961/1418983

Comment: Ok I figured that I can override some values in the helm chart using the values.yml file